# Can I allow access to ONLY the default graph in Apache Jena?

Tags: graph, rdf, jena, triplestore

I know I can select default and/or named graphs for queries, but my question is:

Can I hide any named graphs in Apache Jena from being listed or queried via SPARQL, only allowing access to the default graph (a setting/configuration)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by making a dataset out of the default model.

API:

```
Dataset dataset = ...;
Dataset datasetDefaultOnly = DatasetFactory.wrap(dataset.getDefaultModel);
```

For a Fuseki configuration, the same approach:

```
# Dataset with only the default graph.
:dataset rdf:type       ja:RDFDataset ;
    ja:defaultGraph     :oneGraph
     .

# Graph from a TDB2 dataset
:oneGraph rdf:type tdb2:GraphTDB2 ;
    tdb2:dataset :tdbDataset .

## Data in TDB.
:tdbDataset rdf:type tdb2:DatasetTDB2 ;
    tdb2:location "DB" ;
    .
```

Another approach is to check SPARQL queries to make sure they have no `FROM`, `FROM NAMED` or `GRAPH` in them.

Comment: That's great, thanks!  I'm curious about your second option to pre-parse the query: is this something SPARQL frontends support out of the box?  I was hoping to use the Wikidata Query Service GUI as a SPARQL front-end to Jena...

Comment: If you are calling from Java, the app can parse the query then analyse it to determine whether it has any syntax forms that access named graphs. There are only a few places where named graph are referred to accesses. It does require putting some code into the query evaluation path.

Answer (score 1):

As per AndyS's response, access control in RDF can be implemented at the dataset level; thus, I always advise researchers to create multiple datasets if they have private data that they do not want others to access.
The configuration of shiro makes using the access control implemented in fuseki simple and straightforward. You can restrict access to specific datasets to specific users.

I might add to AndyS's response the option from the Fuseki UI to create multiple datasets and upload the various ttl data files there,  [as per the attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpUmB.png).

Then after each dataset will be available in a separate SPARQL endpoint to share.